# How to fix OpenCV Numpy Error, object is not iterable

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror, nonetype

I'm following a guide to develop a motion detection security feed and have run into an issue. The author of the tutorial had no issues, but I do.

'''The full code can be found here: https://github.com/ncorbuk/Python-Motion-Detection-system/blob/master/motion_detection.py 
'''

I have already tried the option of adding,

" for c in cnt or []: " - This got me further into running the application where I could see the camera screens, however as soon as motion is detected the application crashes and provides the following numpy error:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
>   Use a.any() or a.all()

```
for c in cnt:
        if (cv2.contourArea(c) > 800): 
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2) 

            text = 'Occupied'

        else:
            pass
```

The expected output, if you have a webcam;
When motion is detected a green rectangle will follow the moving pixels and change the mode from Unoccupied to Occupied, in real time; with no errors.

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I'm using opencv-python==4.0.0.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Opencv4.0, `findContour()` returns only 2 values, `contours` and `hierachy`. So in the line 57 in `motion_detection.py` you have to change

`cnt = cv2.findContours(dilate_image.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]`

to

`cnt = cv2.findContours(dilate_image.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ha Bom, your answer has solved my problem!